how to make google pie chart half size?
actually i am generating pie and doughnut chart using google chart. working well. i would like to have half size pie and doughnut chart (see the example images)(https://i.sstatic.net/iNNQ3.png). my code html code.(https://i.sstatic.net/02PjO.png). need half google pie and doughnut chart
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Doughnut Chart!</h1>
    <div id="doughnut3"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="exportButton3">Download</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Load google charts
        google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages': ['corechart']
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        // Draw the chart and set the chart values
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['', ''], ['a', 2], ['b', 2], ['c', 2], ['d', 3], ['e', 3]]);

            // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
            var options = {
                'title': 'Capacité de répondre aux incidents/réclamations',
                'width': 600,
                'height': 400,
                'colors': ['#FF8AA3', '#83C6F5', '#FFE395', '#F1F2F4', '#91D9DA'],
                pieSliceTextStyle: {
                    color: '#000',
                },
                pieHole: 0.4,
            };

            // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
            var chart3 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('doughnut3'));

            // Draw the chart
            chart3.draw(data, options);


            // Export chart function
            document.getElementById('exportButton3').addEventListener('click', function () {
                var uri = chart3.getImageURI();
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = uri;
                link.download = 'capacite.png';
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            });
        }
    </script>


    <div id="pie"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="exportButton1">Download</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Load google charts
        google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages': ['corechart']
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        // Draw the chart and set the chart values
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['', ''], ['a', 2], ['b', 2], ['c', 2], ['d', 3], ['e', 3]]);

            // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
            var options = {
                'title': 'Satisfait de notre réactivité managériale',
                'width': 600,
                'height': 400,
                'colors': ['#FF8AA3', '#83C6F5', '#FFE395', '#F1F2F4', '#91D9DA'],
                pieSliceTextStyle: {
                    color: '#000',
                },
                //pieHole: 0.4,
            };

            // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
            var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie'));

            // Draw the chart
            chart1.draw(data, options);

            // Export chart function
            document.getElementById('exportButton1').addEventListener('click', function () {
                var uri = chart1.getImageURI();
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = uri;
                link.download = 'reactivite.png';
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            });
        }
    </script>
</div>

need half google pie and doughnut chart
